# Android fragment transition: call postponeEnterTransition() only when necessary

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-transitions

I am studying to use fragment transitions, and the basic sample works fine for me.

My request is simple, I have a pager fragment, which is the destination of many other navigation fragments.

So I want to do `postponeEnterTransition()` and `startPostponedEnterTransition()` ONLY when it is necessary.

Because I will only enable the fancy transition in some of the originator fragments, not in all of them.

Is there some method like "`isEnterTransitionAvailable(`)"?

Thanks a lot.